# How to add a increase and decrease button to quantity box

Tags: javascript, php, magento, product

In the product view page, I would like to add a plus and minus button that increases and decreases the number of quantity of product.

Answer (score 2):

Go to,
app\design\frontend\default\your_theme\template\catalog\product\view\addtocart.phml

At around line no 32 search,

`<label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />`

Replace the above with,

`<div>
    <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
        <input class="button-arrow button-up" type="button" value='+'></input>
        <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
        <input class="button-arrow button-down" type="button" value='-'></input>
</div>`

At the end of that .phtml file paste,

`<script type="text/javascript">
        //&lt;![CDATA[
        jQuery(function($) {
            $('.add-to-cart .button-up').click(function() {
                $qty = $(this).parent().find('.qty');
                qty = parseInt($qty.val()) + 1;
                $qty.val(qty);
            });
            $('.add-to-cart .button-down').click(function() {
                $qty = $(this).parent().find('.qty');
                qty = parseInt($qty.val()) - 1;
                if (qty < 0)
                    qty = 0;
                $qty.val(qty);
            });
        });
     //]]&gt;
</script>`

Comment: I'm also struggling with adding in top links, the options I require is My account My cart checkout log in. I need it to display in line, which also will need to be dynamic as when you log in

Comment: It's a different question, post another one with more details. But before posting that try to search solution. If you are using ajax for login then you have to update particular block using ajax to see change. For top link you can follow these links, [Top menu 1](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/22425/add-new-links-to-top-links-in-magento-1-9) and [Top menu 2](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/09/07/magento-add-top-links-in-magento/)

Comment: In magento 2,  Change class name 'add-to-cart' to 'box-tocart'  ie,  box-tocart $('.add-to-cart .button-up')   to  $('.'box-tocart .button-up')

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML5 input type "number"

Please check for all browsers before make it live.