# Increasing and decreasing the quantity using buttons f

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I need to add functions to the buttons.I tried to add that to the php file.

Script is here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $document.on('click','#minus_button',function(){
            selected=$(this.attr("data-id"));

            quantity = parseInt($('#quantity[data-id="'+selected'"]').val());

            $('#quantity[data-id="'+selected'"]').val(quantity -1);


        });

        $document.on('click','#plus_button',function(){
            selected=$(this.attr("data-id"));

            quantity = parseInt($('#quantity[data-id="'+selected'"]').val());

            $('#quantity[data-id="'+selected'"]').val(quantity + 1);

        });
    });
```

Here is the buttons:

```
<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn bg-light border rounded-circle\" id=\"minus_button\" data-id=\"$productid\"><i class=\"fas fa-minus\"></i></button>
<input type=\"text\" value=\"1\" class=\"form-control w-25 d-inline\" id=\"quantity\" data-id=\"$productid\">
<button type=\"button\" class=\" btn bg-light border rounded-circle\"id=\"plus_button\" data-id=\"$productid\"><i class=\"fas fa-plus\"></i></button>
```

I get the product_id from database.Buttons do not work.I would be glad if you help.

Comment: So you add event listeners to the button. click event, update the value. (Or use input `type="number" which has them built in)

Comment: Is what you posted inside php? The escaped quotes suggests it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I know it can be hard to come up with the right keywords for searching, but pls do try before posting a new question.  I just tried "javascript buttons increase quantity" and turned up many answers here with code you can use, for eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186346/javascript-onclick-increment-number, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36567460/how-to-add-a-increase-and-decrease-button-to-quantity-box, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50086238/javascript-increase-button-increases-only-once ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript onclick increment number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186346/javascript-onclick-increment-number)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner could you reopen that ?

Answer (score 0):

Your current jquery code has many syntax error i have corrected that .Also,instead of `id` i have use here `class` because you might be having many button with same id .

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.minus_button', function() {
    selected = $(this).attr("data-id");
    quantity = parseInt($('.quantity[data-id="' + selected + '"]').val());
    $('.quantity[data-id="' + selected + '"]').val(quantity - 1);
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.plus_button', function() {
    selected = $(this).attr("data-id");

    quantity = parseInt($('.quantity[data-id="' + selected + '"]').val());

    $('.quantity[data-id="' + selected + '"]').val(quantity + 1);

  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--added class="minus_button"-->
<button type="button" class="btn bg-light border rounded-circle minus_button" id="minus_button" data-id="$productid"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
<!--added class="quantity"-->
<input type="text" value="1" class="form-control w-25 d-inline quantity" id="quantity" data-id="$productid">
<!--added class="plus_button"-->
<button type="button" class=" btn bg-light border rounded-circle plus_button" id="plus_button" data-id="$productid"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer it really worked.I have a another question.After I added your script I need to calculate the total price by quantitiy.But I couldn't be able to that.

Comment: where is your total price display? can you add more html code?

Answer (score 0):

And also that script to calculate total price.But in this manner,I need add quantity on it.When I tried to add that it doesn't work.

```
<?php

                $total = 0;
                    if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
                        $product_id = array_column($_SESSION['cart'], 'product_id');

                        $result = $db->getData();
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                            foreach ($product_id as $id){
                                if ($row['id'] == $id){
                                    cartElement($row['product_image'], $row['product_name'],$row['product_price'], $row['id']);
                                    $total = $total + (int)$row['product_price'];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        echo "<h5>Cart is Empty</h5>";
                    }

                ?>
```